# How to create independent LSTM cells in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to make a RNN classifier that has 3 different time series with 3 dimensions each as input and the time series can have different lengths. So to solve that, I modeled 3 RNNs and connected them in the final layer.

However, I am getting the following error message:

> ValueError: Variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel
>   already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in
>   VarScope?

```py
timeSeries = ['outbound', 'rest', 'return']
n_steps = {
    'outbound': 3159,
    'rest': 3603,
    'return': 3226
}
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 20
n_outputs = 2
n_layers = 1

learning_rate = 0.001


y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="y")
X = {}
seq_length = {}
for timeSeriesName in timeSeries:
    with tf.name_scope(timeSeriesName + "_placeholders") as scope:
        X[timeSeriesName] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps[timeSeriesName], n_inputs])
        seq_length[timeSeriesName] = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])


outputs = {}
states = {}
top_layer_h_state = {}
lstm_cells = {}
multi_cell = {}
finalRNNlayers = []
for timeSeriesName in timeSeries:
    with tf.name_scope(timeSeriesName) as scope:
        lstm_cells[timeSeriesName] = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)
                                      for layer in range(n_layers)]
        multi_cell[timeSeriesName] = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells[timeSeriesName])
        outputs[timeSeriesName], states[timeSeriesName] = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            multi_cell[timeSeriesName], X[timeSeriesName], dtype=tf.float32,
            sequence_length=seq_length[timeSeriesName])
        top_layer_h_state[timeSeriesName] = states[timeSeriesName][-1][1]
        finalRNNlayers.append(top_layer_h_state[timeSeriesName])

with tf.name_scope("3Stages_mixed") as scope:
    concat3_top_layer_h_states = tf.concat(finalRNNlayers, axis=1)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(concat3_top_layer_h_states, n_outputs, name="softmax")
```

I want each time series to have independent LSTM cells with their own weights each, so the reuse is not an option, how should this error be fixed?

[The full traceback of the error can be found here](https://pastebin.ca/3905734).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `tf.name_scope(timeSeriesName)` to `tf.variable_scope(timeSeriesName)`. The difference between `tf.name_scope` and `tf.variable_scope` is discussed in [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919020/712995). In your case, what's important is that `tf.get_variable` ignores the name scopes and LSTM cell parameters are created exactly with `tf.get_variable`.

Sample code to see the difference:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

state = tf.zeros([32, 6])

input1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [32, 10])
input2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [32, 10])

# Works ok:
with tf.variable_scope('scope-1'):
  tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3, state_is_tuple=False)(input1, state)
with tf.variable_scope('scope-2'):
  tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3, state_is_tuple=False)(input2, state)

# Fails:
with tf.name_scope('name-1'):
  tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3, state_is_tuple=False)(input1, state)
with tf.name_scope('name-2'):
  tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(3, state_is_tuple=False)(input2, state)
```