# Tensorflow convolution layers have strange artefacts

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-layers

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong that my tensorboard graphs have additional groups when I use `tf.layers.conv1d` ?

For sake of simplicity I've created one `tf.name_scope` 'conv_block1' that contains: `conv1d -> max_pool -> batch_norm`, yet my graph has odd addtional blocks (see attached screenshot). Basically a superficial block 'conv1d`was added with weights for the`conv_block1/conv1d` layer, and it is placed an groups. This makes the networks with multiple convolution blocks completely unreadable, am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug/performance feature in Tensorflow 1.4? Odd enough the dense layers are fine and the weights are properly scoped.

[image: Graph naming issue described above]

Here is the code if anyone wants to recreate the graph:

```
def cnn_model(inputs, mode):
  x = tf.placeholder_with_default(inputs['wav'], shape=[None, SAMPLE_RATE, 1],  name='input_placeholder')

  with tf.name_scope("conv_block1"):
    x = tf.layers.conv1d(x, filters=80, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(x, pool_size=3, strides=3)
    x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

  x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=12)
  return x
```

### UPDATE 1

I've added even simpler example that can be executed directly to see the issue:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  x = tf.placeholder(name='input', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 16000, 1])
  with tf.name_scope('group1'):
    x = tf.layers.conv1d(x, 80, 5, name='conv1')
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 10, name="dense1")
[n.name for n in g.as_graph_def().node]
```

outputs:

```
['input',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul',
 'conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform',
 'conv1/kernel',
 'conv1/kernel/Assign',
 'conv1/kernel/read',
 'conv1/bias/Initializer/zeros',
 'conv1/bias',
 'conv1/bias/Assign',
 'conv1/bias/read',
 'group1/conv1/dilation_rate',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims/dim',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1/dim',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/Conv2D',
 'group1/conv1/conv1d/Squeeze',
 'group1/conv1/BiasAdd',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul',
 'dense1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform',
 'dense1/kernel',
 'dense1/kernel/Assign',
 'dense1/kernel/read',
 'dense1/bias/Initializer/zeros',
 'dense1/bias',
 'dense1/bias/Assign',
 'dense1/bias/read',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Shape',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Rank',
 'dense1/Tensordot/axes',
 'dense1/Tensordot/GreaterEqual/y',
 'dense1/Tensordot/GreaterEqual',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Cast',
 'dense1/Tensordot/mul',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Less/y',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Less',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Cast_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/add',
 'dense1/Tensordot/mul_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/add_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/range/start',
 'dense1/Tensordot/range/delta',
 'dense1/Tensordot/range',
 'dense1/Tensordot/ListDiff',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Gather',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Gather_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Const',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Prod',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Const_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Prod_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat/axis',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat_1/axis',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/stack',
 'dense1/Tensordot/transpose',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Reshape',
 'dense1/Tensordot/transpose_1/perm',
 'dense1/Tensordot/transpose_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Reshape_1/shape',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Reshape_1',
 'dense1/Tensordot/MatMul',
 'dense1/Tensordot/Const_2',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat_2/axis',
 'dense1/Tensordot/concat_2',
 'dense1/Tensordot',
 'dense1/BiasAdd']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the issue apparently `tf.name_scope` is for operation only and `tf.variable_scope` works for both operations and variables ([as per this tf issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15630)).

Here is a stack overflow question that explains the difference between name_scope and variable_scope:
[What's the difference of name scope and a variable scope in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow)

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  x = tf.placeholder(name='input', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 16000, 1])
  with tf.variable_scope('v_scope1'):
    x = tf.layers.conv1d(x, 80, 5, name='conv1')
[n.name for n in g.as_graph_def().node]
```

gives:

```
['input',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/Assign',
 'v_scope1/conv1/kernel/read',
 'v_scope1/conv1/bias/Initializer/zeros',
 'v_scope1/conv1/bias',
 'v_scope1/conv1/bias/Assign',
 'v_scope1/conv1/bias/read',
 'v_scope1/conv1/dilation_rate',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims/dim',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1/dim',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/Conv2D',
 'v_scope1/conv1/conv1d/Squeeze',
 'v_scope1/conv1/BiasAdd']
```