# Tensorflow sharing variables under different variable_scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scope, reinforcement-learning

I have three networks, call them V, V_target, and Actor, and I'm trying to achieve the following setup:

1. V and Actor share certain layers.
2. V_target is an exact duplicate of V.

For those familiar with deep RL, I'm using this within an actor-critic algorithm with shared layers between the value and policy networks, plus a target network V_target. I tried the following:

```
def shared(...):
  # define some variables, e.g.
  W = get_variable('W', ...)

def Actor(...):
  with tf.variable_scope("shared"):
    shared_out = shared(...)
  ... actor-specific layers ...

def V(...):
  with tf.variable_scope("shared", reuse=True):
    shared_out = shared(...)
  ... V-specific layers...

with tf.variable_scope("Policy"):
  actor_out = Actor(...)
with tf.variable_scope("V_main"):
  V_out = V(...)
with tf.variable_scope("V_target"):
  V_target = V(...)
```

As expected, this doesn't work because the use of the outermost `variable_scope` prevents sharing between Policy and V_main: the Variable `W` has name `Policy/shared/W` in one scope but has name `V_main/shared/W` under the second scope.

Why not use `tf.name_scope("Policy")` and `tf.name_scope("V_main")`? If I do that, the `shared` variables can be defined, but then I don't have a good way to get the variables under `V_main` and `V_target`. Specifically, because `tf.name_scope` does not append anything to names created by `tf.get_variable`, I cannot use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES ,'V_main')` and `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES ,'V_target')` to get both sets of objects for the so-called "target updates".

Is there any clever way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the trick described in this question: [How to create variable outside of current scope in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48650889/712995)

> You can clear the current variable scope by providing an instance of an existing scope.

So you simply need to define `tf.variable_scope("shared")` once, remember the reference to this instance and use it inside all other variable scopes (with `reuse=True`). `W` variable will be created in `shared` scope, no matter what the outer scope is.

Comment: Since this clears the current scope and replaces it with `shared`, `W` won't have the string "V_main" in its name, which probably means I can't use tf.get_collection(..., 'V_main') to retrieve it. Perhaps there isn't a perfect solution, and I just need to use a more roundabout variable retrieval method.