# Any way not to inherit parent variable_scope?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose that I have following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.variable_scope('Embedding'):
    embd = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix', [100, 10], dtype = tf.float32)
```

And I want to reuse the tensor with name `embedding_matrix` within new scope:

```
with tf.variable_scope('not_related'):
    with tf.variable_scope('Embedding', reuse = True) as scope:
        # I want the name of 'call_embd' be 'Embedding/embedding_matrix
        # but not 'not_related/Embedding/embedding_matrix'
        call_embd = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix')
```

Any way to let `call_embd` has name `Embedding/embedding_matrix` ?

Comment: You could hack your way around this, but you're really not supposed to. What are you trying to do? This is precisely what variable_scope is supposed to prevent.

Comment: I just want to make `variable_scope` for each part of the code. I made `variable_scope('SharedScope')` for those basic operation like embedding_lookup with embedding matrix generation. Another scope  maybe `variable_scope('DecodeScope') `that wants to use the embedding that was generated in the `SharedScope`.  However, I actually called an `embedding_op` function to return embedded variable given inputs(inside `SharedScope`) that i can't directly reach the embedding matrix. @Zvika

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification comment, it sounds like you are confusing `variable_scope` with `name_scope`.

In brief:

- `variable_scope` is used to avoid different parts of the code from unintentionally reusing the same variables.
- `name_scope` is used to logically group ops.

So in your case, you'd use something like:

```
with tf.name_scope('Encoding'):
  with tf.variable_scope('Embedding'):
    embd = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix', [100, 10], dtype = tf.float32)
    # ... use this var
# ... later ...
with tf.name_scope('Decoding'):
  with tf.variable_scope('Embedding', reuse=True):
    embd = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix')
    # ... reuse this var
```

More on the (admittedly confusing) distinction between `name_scope` and `variable_scope` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow/37534656).