# How to put tf.layers variables in tf.name_scope/tf.variable_scope?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope, layer, tensorboard

I have a problem with Tensorflow:

The following code produces a correct(ish) graph for a convolutional block:

```
def conv_layer(self, inputs, filter_size = 3, num_filters = 256, name = None):
    scope_name = name
    if name == None:
        scope_name = "conv_layer"

    with tf.name_scope(scope_name):
        conv = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs, num_filters, filter_size, activation_fn = None)
        batch_norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv)
        act = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_norm)

        return act
```

The problem is that the `tf.layers` API makes some ugly variables that do not actually stay within the `name_scope`. Here is the Tensorboard view so you can see what I mean.

[image: Tensorboard]

Is there anyway to get those variables to go into the scope? This is a big problem when it comes to visualizing the graph because I plan this network to much larger. (As you can see to the right, this is already a big problem, I have to remove those from the main graph manually every time I boot up Tensorboard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `tf.variable_scope` instead. `tf.name_scope` is ignored by variables created via `tf.get_variable()` which is usually used by `tf.layers` functions. This is in contrast to variables created via `tf.Variable`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow) for an (albeit somewhat outdated) explanation of the differences.

Comment: Upon changing the `name_scope` to `variable_scope`, I get the following error
`ValueError: Variable conv_layer/Conv/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

Comment: Also, setting the `reuse` perimeter of the `variable_scope` to true yields this error: `Variable conv_layer/Conv/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

Comment: It appears I have found a work around by giving each `variable_scope` a unique id. I will make an edit to my post to display my solution (more of a work around).

Comment: So now there is something called tf.variable_creator_scope and no variable_scope.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution moved from question to an answer:*

Changing each instance of `name_scope` with `variable_scope` the problem has been omitted. However, I had to assign each `variable_scope` with a unique ID and set `reuse = False`.

```
def conv_layer(self, inputs, filter_size = 3, num_filters = 256, name = None):
    scope_name = name
    if name == None:
        scope_name = "conv_layer_" + str(self.conv_id)
        self.conv_id += 1

    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse = False):
        conv = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs, num_filters, filter_size, activation_fn = None)
        batch_norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv)
        act = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_norm)

        return act
```

As you can see, the variables are nicely hidden away in the correct blocks.

[image: solution]