# TensorFlow: How can I add an image decoder node to my graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I have a tensorflow model as a frozen graph, which accepts an image tensor as an input. However, I'd like to add a new input image decoder node to this graph, so that the model also accepts an encoded byte string of a jpg image and eventually decodes the image by itself. I've tried this approach so far:

```
model = './frozen_graph.pb'

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(model, 'rb') as f:

    # read graph
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    # fetch old input
    old_input = g.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    # define new input
    new_input = graph_def.node.add()
    new_input.name = 'encoded_image_string_tensor'
    new_input.op = 'Substr'
    # add new input attr
    image = tf.image.decode_image(new_input, channels=3)

    # link new input to old input
    old_input.input = 'encoded_image_string_tensor'  #  must match with the name above
```

The above code returns this exception:

```
Expected string passed to parameter 'input' of op 'Substr', got name: "encoded_image_string_tensor" op: "Substr"  of type 'NodeDef' instead.
```

I'm not quite sure if I can use the `tf.image.decode_image` within a graph, so maybe there's another way to solve this problem. Anybody got a hint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but [`tf.import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) has an `input_map` parameter where you can map existing nodes in the graph to nodes in the graph definition. That would allow you to change how the input data gets into the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782792/jdehesa), who gave me a good hint, I was able to solve this problem. With the `input_map` parameter I successfully mapped a new graph, which just decodes jpg images, to the input of my original graph (here: `node.name='image_tensor:0'`). Just make sure, that you rename the `name_scope` of the decoder graph (here: `decoder`).
After that, you can save the new concatenated graph by using the tensorflow SavedModelBuilder.

Here an example of an object detection network:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants


# The export path contains the name and the version of the model
model = 'path/to/model.pb'
export_path = './output/dir/'

sigs = {}

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(model, 'rb') as f:
        with tf.name_scope('decoder'):
                image_str_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None], name= 'encoded_image_string_tensor')
                # The CloudML Prediction API always "feeds" the Tensorflow graph with
                # dynamic batch sizes e.g. (?,).  decode_jpeg only processes scalar
                # strings because it cannot guarantee a batch of images would have
                # the same output size.  We use tf.map_fn to give decode_jpeg a scalar
                # string from dynamic batches.
                def decode_and_resize(image_str_tensor):
                        """Decodes jpeg string, resizes it and returns a uint8 tensor."""
                        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_str_tensor, channels=3)

                        # do additional image manipulation here (like resize etc...)

                        image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
                        return image

                image = tf.map_fn(decode_and_resize, image_str_tensor, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.uint8)

        with tf.name_scope('net'):
                # load .pb file
                graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
                graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

                # concatenate decoder graph and original graph
                tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="", input_map={'image_tensor:0':image})
                g = tf.get_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:
        # load graph into session and save to new .pb file

        # define model input
        inp = g.get_tensor_by_name('decoder/encoded_image_string_tensor:0')

        # define model outputs
        num_detections = g.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        detection_scores = g.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_boxes = g.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        out = {'num_detections': num_detections, 'detection_scores': detection_scores, 'detection_boxes': detection_boxes}


        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

        tensor_info_inputs = {
                'inputs': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(inp)}
        tensor_info_outputs = {}
        for k, v in out.items():
                tensor_info_outputs[k] = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(v)

        # assign detection signature for tensorflow serving
        detection_signature = (
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                inputs=tensor_info_inputs,
                outputs=tensor_info_outputs,
                method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

        # "build" graph
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                signature_def_map={
                'detection_signature':
                        detection_signature,
                signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
                        detection_signature,
                },
                main_op=tf.tables_initializer()
        )
        # save graph
        builder.save()
```

Sources I used to find the right solution:

[Coding example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/model.py#L132)

[Scope names explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow)

[Tensorflow Github Issue #22162](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22162)

Additionally:
If you struggle with finding the right input and output nodes, you can run this to display the graph:

```py
graph_op = g.get_operations()
for i in graph_op:
    print(i.node_def)
```