# When do I have to explicitly use the reuse option in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

in the Tensorflow Documentation it says, that everything within a `variable_scope` inherits the `reuse` option like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope("name", reuse=True):
    # inherits reuse=True
```

But my question is when I for example use one of these helper methods:

```
fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))

norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, 0.9, epsilon=1e-5, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, scope=scope, fused=True)
```

Do I have to set the options: `reuse` and `scope` explicitly like this:

```
fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False), scope=scope, reuse=True)

norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, 0.9, epsilon=1e-5, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, scope=scope, reuse=True, is_training=self.is_training, fused=True)
```

or how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to set the options: reuse and scope explicitly like this:

`reuse` parameter is designed to reuse existing variables [Sharing Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope) in between different ops in the graph. During a neural network training step parameters are learned; so to use those learned parameters during validation you can retrieve the variables using `reuse` parameters without resetting the values or without recreating those variables.

It is good practice to keep track of the `reuse` parameters

```
# a usual CNN model definition with reuse parameter
def model(input, reuse=None):
    fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 512,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,   
         weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False),   
         scope=scope, reuse=reuse)

    norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, 0.9, epsilon=1e-5,
        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, scope=scope, reuse=reuse, 
        is_training=self.is_training, fused=True)
    ...


# Now for training; setting reuse=None creates the graph variables
some_ouput = model(input, reuse=None)

# Now for validation; setting reuse=True; retrieve the learned variables for validation without creating new one.
some_output = model(input, reuse=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, google around! This should answer your question: [Tensorflow variable scope: reuse if variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545362/tensorflow-variable-scope-reuse-if-variable-exists)

But if not..
You need to call reuse if you actually reuse a part of your model, not if you use the layer. Lets say that you have a function defined as:

```
def func(input,scope=scope, reuse=reuse):
    fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, ..., scope=scope, reuse=reuse)
    norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(fc, ..., scope=scope, reuse=reuse) 
    return norm
```

Scope will define a name space of variables (read more about the scope [What's the difference of name scope and a variable scope in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow), https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/variable-sharing-in-tensorflow/, [Understanding Variable scope example in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725159/understanding-variable-scope-example-in-tensorflow)), so once you run your function with scope='scp' and input.shape=(1,2,3), you will not be able to run the same function with the same scope and input.shape=(3,4,5), since the variable with given scope and a different shape already exists.
Therefore you should use reuse=True the second time you call your function.

Comment: That does not answer my question at all! I was asking, whether I have to explicitly set the scope=scope, reuse=reuse or if I can just leave it when I use tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=True) as scope:..

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you, sorry. Yet, your question can be answered by reading about scopes. https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope
Generally - no, you don't need to put reuse as an argument any more. Still, scoping doesn't make much sense in your case, as the code you wrote will always work with a new input. As I mentioned, scopes are useful once you actually define your own model you want to reuse. I hope that helps you more.